# How to prevent bot from spamming? | Twitch.py | Discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, twitch

I'm new to python and i'm making discord bot. So here i have twitch notification function, but when someone is live bot just starts spamming, i think because idk how to get `content` out of an embed. please help me. the code:

```
import os
import json
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

TOKEN = os.getenv('token')

# Authentication with Twitch API.
client_id = os.getenv('client_id')
client_secret = os.getenv('Dweller_token')
body = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    "grant_type": 'client_credentials'
}
r = requests.post('https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token', body)
keys = r.json()
headers = {
    'Client-ID': client_id,
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + keys['access_token']
}

'''user_info = twitch.get_users(logins=['turb4ik'])
user_id = user_info['data'][0]['id']
print(user_info)'''

# Returns true if online, false if not.
def checkuser(streamer_name):
    stream = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=' + streamer_name, headers=headers)
    stream_data = stream.json()

    if len(stream_data['data']) == 1:
        return True, stream_data
    else:
        return False, stream_data


# Executes when bot is started
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Defines a loop that will run every 10 seconds (checks for live users every 10 seconds).
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def live_notifs_loop():
        # username = stream_data['data'][0]['user_name']
        # stream_title = stream_data['data'][0]['title']
        # game_being_played = stream_data['data'][0]['game_name']

        # Opens and reads the json file
        with open('streamers.json', 'r') as file:
            streamers = json.loads(file.read())
        # Makes sure the json isn't empty before continuing.
        if streamers is not None:
            # Gets the guild, 'twitch streams' channel, and streaming role.
            guild = bot.get_guild(690995360411156531)
            channel = bot.get_channel(798127930295058442)
            role = get(guild.roles, id=835581408272580649)
            # Loops through the json and gets the key,value which in this case is the user_id and twitch_name of
            # every item in the json.
            for user_id, twitch_name in streamers.items():
                print("checking" + " " + str(twitch_name))
                # Takes the given twitch_name and checks it using the checkuser function to see if they're live.
                # Returns either true or false.
                status, stream_data = checkuser(twitch_name)
                # Gets the user using the collected user_id in the json
                user = bot.get_user(int(user_id))
                # Makes sure they're live
                if status is True:
                    # Checks to see if the live message has already been sent.
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
                        print("yes")
                        twitch_embed = discord.Embed(
                                title=f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! \n \n {stream_data['data'][0]['title']}",
                                color=0xac1efb,
                                url=f'\nhttps://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}'
                            )
                        twitch_embed.add_field(
                              name = '**Game**',
                              value = stream_data['data'][0]['game_name'], 
                              inline = True
                            )
                        twitch_embed.add_field(
                              name = '**Viewers**',
                              value = stream_data['data'][0]['viewer_count'], 
                              inline = True
                            )
                        twitch_embed.set_author(
                                name = str(twitch_name),
                                icon_url = stream_data['data'][0]['thumbnail_url']
                                                            )
                        twitch_embed.set_image(url = f'https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}')
                        print("yes2")
                        try:
                            embed_title = twitch_embed.title
                            embed_description = twitch_embed.description
                        except Exception as e:
                            break
                        print("yes3")

                        # If it has, break the loop (do nothing).
                        if embed_title == True:
                            break
                        # If it hasn't, assign them the streaming role and send the message.
                        else:
                            # Gets all the members in your guild.
                            async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                                # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and
                                # they're live, give them the streaming role.
                                if member.id == int(user_id):
                                    await member.add_roles(role)
                            # Sends the live notification to the 'twitch streams' channel then breaks the loop.
                            await channel.send(
                                content = f"Hey @everyone! {user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! Go check it out: https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}", embed=twitch_embed)
                            print(f"{user} started streaming. Sending a notification.")
                            break
                # If they aren't live do this:
                else:
                    # Gets all the members in your guild.
                    async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                        # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and they're not
                        # live, remove the streaming role.
                        if member.id == int(user_id):
                            await member.remove_roles(role)
                    # Checks to see if the live notification was sent.
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
                        try:
                            embed_title = message.embeds[0].title
                            embed_description = message.embeds[0].description
                        except Exception as e:
                            break
                        # If it was, delete it.
                        if user.mention in embed_title and "is now playing" in embed_title:
                            print(f"{user} stopped streaming. Removing the notification.")
                            await message.delete()
    # Start your loop.
    live_notifs_loop.start()


# Command to add Twitch usernames to the json.
@bot.command(name='addtwitch', help='Adds your Twitch to the live notifs.', pass_context=True)
async def add_twitch(ctx, twitch_name):
    # Opens and reads the json file.
    with open('streamers.json', 'r') as file:
        streamers = json.loads(file.read())

    # Gets the users id that called the command.
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    # Assigns their given twitch_name to their discord id and adds it to the streamers.json.
    streamers[user_id] = twitch_name

    # Adds the changes we made to the json file.
    with open('streamers.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(streamers))
    # Tells the user it worked.
    await ctx.send(f"Added {twitch_name} for {ctx.author} to the notifications list.")


print('Server Running')
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Answer (score 0):

*Just for others context, he had shown me the error on discord, so I am answering him through this question!*

So mate, I found the error.

The line 106 in your code is:

```
await message.channel.send(msg)
```

Now this `msg` variable send all the details but we just want the content of it and not anything else.

So change that to:

```
await message.channel.send(msg.content)
```

Thank You! :D